# Use iPython notebook in a proxy

Tags: proxy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

does anyone know how to set iPython notebook in a proxy environment?

When I tried below code,

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.url

It showed:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='mhsproxy.datastream.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This as nothing to do with the fact that you are using an IPython notebook, the notebook itself seem to work great as you can code in it.

What you are looking for is how to set up a proxy when you use the `requests` library.